# Angular JS- One service depending on another service does not see the updates to the service

Tags: angularjs

I have two services. One depends on the other. I also have a controller that depends on both the services and updates value in one of the services. The other service does not see the update.

Below I have a controller that updates one service but the update never reflects in the other service. I want the `serviceOne`'s `calculatedVal` to reflect changes in `serviceTwo`'s `changingVal`. Any advice is appreciated.
Fiddle at the end.

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="con">
    <h1 ng-click="showOnConsole()">
    click
    </h1>    
    {{serviceOneStr}}
    <br/>
    {{serviceTwoStr}}
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.service('serviceOne', function(serviceTwo) {
    this.calculatedVal = "some string" + " " + serviceTwo.changingVal;
});

myApp.service('serviceTwo', function() {
    this.changingVal = "version 1";
});

//Controller
myApp.controller("con",function($scope, $timeout, serviceOne, serviceTwo){
    var counter = 0;
  $scope.serviceOneStr = "Initialized One";
  $scope.serviceTwoStr = "Initialized Two";

  $scope.showOnConsole = function(){
    counter = counter + 1;
    serviceTwo.changingVal = "version " + counter;
    $scope.serviceOneStr = JSON.stringify(serviceOne);
    $scope.serviceTwoStr = JSON.stringify(serviceTwo);
    console.log(serviceOne);
    console.log(serviceTwo);
  }
})
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h1snj8jw/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always find these situations easier to address by using a factory with a getter/setter. Here's one way you could implement this approach - change your `.service` modules to `.factory` like this:

```
myApp.factory('serviceOne', function(serviceTwo) {
    var service = {
        get calculatedVal() {
            return "some string " + serviceTwo.changingVal;
        }
    }
    return service;
});

myApp.factory('serviceTwo', function() {
    var changingVal = "version 1";
    var service = {
        get changingVal() {
            return changingVal;
        },
        set changingVal(value) {
            changingVal = value;
        }
    }
    return service;
});
```

Comment: Can I just swap in factories for services? I was under the impression that services are singletons and factories are not.

Comment: They are both services (and therefore both singletons), just different service patterns. One (service pattern) uses `this.` notation while the other (factory pattern) must return an object.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: Change `calculatedVal` to a function so it will always have the most up to date value of `changingVal`.

```
myApp.service('serviceOne', function(serviceTwo) {
    this.calculatedVal = function() {
       return "some string" + " " + serviceTwo.changingVal;
    };
});
```

I'd like to explain why what you're doing doesn't work, so you can understand the fix for it.

Services in angular are singletons. The declaration of a service is ran only once and stored. So when you set a property on a service to a string or number (value types), that's the value it will have for it's lifetime unless it is set otherwise.

For this line:

```
this.calculatedVal = "some string" + " " + serviceTwo.changingVal;
```

It sets the value of `calculatedVal` off of the initial value of `serviceTwo.changingVal`. There's not any magic behind the scenes where angular watches the value of changingVal and updates `calculatedVal`. That's why you need a function to get the computed value.